# IF/ELSE password in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android programming so please forgive me if this is a stupid query.

I have an Edittext for a password field, and a button to submit the password. I also have a couple of Textviews which are hidden (shows if password is correct/incorrect), which I'd like to turn visible using an if/else statement.

When I run the code (on an AVD), nothing happens when I click the submit button. At all, ever.

I *know* this is probably really simple, but looking at other answers on questions similar to this was no help, I've been trying for days to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

..So *ANY* help would be really really appreciated. Thank you!! :D

-I use Eclipse, and Android 4.2.2

Here's the Java part:

```
final TextView success = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
final TextView failure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
Button firstButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
final EditText userPassword  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
firstButton.setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){ 
        if(userPassword.getText().toString() == "pa$$word"){
            success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
           failure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

XML:

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/button" 
android:layout_marginBottom="75dp" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:id="@+id/button1"/> 

<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:id="@+id/passwordField" 
android:inputType="textPassword" 
android:ems="10" 
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"> 

<requestFocus/> 
</EditText> 
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@+string/pwCorrect"
 android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_above="@+id/passwordField"
 android:visibility="gone"/> 

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="@+string/pwIncorrect" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:id="@+id/textView2" 
android:visibility="gone" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Comment: You should compare strings with equals, not `==`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(userPassword.getText().toString() == "pa$$word"){
```

`String`s in java have to compared with `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`. Using `==` you will compare the address of the String

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it still doesn't work with 'if(userPassword.getText().toString().equals("pa$$word"))'

Comment: what does "it does not work" mean ? What are you expectiong to happen?

Comment: i'm hoping it'll show one of the textviews i hid in there

Comment: either will do! i just want to know it can read the input

Comment: he's text is pwCorrect and pwInCorrect.. My guess is that he's positioning those textview out of line

Comment: it definitely didn't like pwCorrect/pwIncorrect. i *think* the id's are fine, although i'm not entirely sure why i have "pwCorrect" and "pwIncorrect" at all if theyre not id's, there must be some reason though

Comment: You should remove + from @+string, it should be @string/pwCorrect and @string/pwInCorrect

Comment: still made no difference. i'm sorry my ide hates me :-(

Comment: are you able to see it in the Android Xml Graphical editor ?

Comment: just when i change it back to android:visibility="visible"

Comment: Can you see both of them?

Comment: yep, as long as they're  both visible

Comment: are you sure the onClick is fired? Comment all your code and put only success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: what am i looking for when i do that?

Comment: Imo the onClick is not fired. Can you check with the debugger or adding a Log?

Comment: I think you're right i just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What does "I think you're right" mean ? what have you tried

Comment: i don't think onClick is running because someone mentioned something about it earlier today but supposedly fixed it. i've not tried anything new

Answer (score 2):

Compare string with `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`

try this

```
if(userPassword.getText().toString().equals("pa$$word"))
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings in Java you want to use the following syntax:

```
if(userPassword.getText().toString().equals("pa$$word"))
```

Also, I don't think the `final` is necessary on your `EditTexts`.

Comment: I don't know why I have them, Eclipse told me I needed them. 
Thank you for the help, unfortunately it's still not doing anything.

Comment: Can you post your entire AlertDialog java code?

Comment: @user2428680 if you don't need final modifier declare edittext as a class variable. Initialize in onCreate()

Comment: Actually, I think those do need to be `final` since they're being accessed from an anonymous inner class.

Comment: it's not an alertDialog.. i'm REALLY new to this, it's just on a page. @Raghunandan, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use this, sometime password are in alphabet with caps-lock so better use equalsIgnoreCase

```
if(userPassword.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pa$$word"))
```

Comment: For passwords, I don't think you'd want `equalsIgnoreCase()`. They are generally case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

use this code snippet

```
if(userPassword.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("your valid passwor")){

    // do something
```

}else{

```
 //wrong password
```

}

enjoy:)
Please don't forget to give +1

Comment: This is my first time not-lurking on this site so I can't +1, sorry :-(

Comment: For passwords, I don't think you'd want `equalsIgnoreCase()`. They are generally case-sensitive.

Comment: yeah you are rite..please use equals() in place of equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: that didn't work, read the top comments for my current status. i'm getting nowhere fast!